# How to mathematically define a noisy contour?

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, math, image-processing

Look at the following image:

[image]

As you can see, some regions are very noisy (very jagged edges with lot of sudden changes)

I would like to eliminate these regions from the image, but to do so I need to be able to determine what this "noise" means.

I have thought about measuring angle changes in consecutive contour points and use that to determine whether something is noisy or not, but I am not confident this is a robust noise region detection.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to mathematically define these regions?

Comment: Fractal dimension might be overkill. Integrated curvature?

Comment: For your measurement of angle changes to be meaningful, they need to be relative to a fixed-size scope when comparing parts of the image. I've added a suggestion for how you might approach this, below.

Comment: The simplest crude check that might work would be check the ratio of perimeter to area. A better way would be to go around the contour clockwise, and sum the (absolute) angle from one point to the next. Highly varying angles on a contour will give a very large sum of absolute angles. However this isn't robust to the size of the contour, so you might want to take perimeter or area into account with a division. This is basically a poor-mans version of Andras' suggestion to take the integrated curvature. Edit: I didn't realize you posted this idea in the question itself.

Comment: Do you have the image without the white contours? Segmentation procedures do not generate thick contours (or contours at all), its generally just a visualization tool. flamelite's answer seems to do the job, but he simply does not have access to independent contours so the result is bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to define the noisy contours by analyzing their curvature values.
Here are the implementation details:

```
1. Threshold the gray scale image using fixed threshold value of 250 to retrieve the white edges

2.Extract the contours in the threshold image

3.Calculate the curvature values along each contour

4.From the curvature data we can observer that the noisy contour's curvature values has higher variance value, therefore we can classify such
noisy contours using certain threshold value.
```

Below is the Python implementation of the above steps.
 Here i am using curvature estimation equation for cartesian coordinates system as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature)

```
#function to calculate the curvature values along a given contour and classify noisy contour
def contourCurvature(contourspt):
    #curvature value estimation using symmetric derivation
    # at points (i-step), i, (i+step)
    step = 5
    s1 = 2*step
    s2 = np.power(s1, 2)
    if len(contourspt) < s1:
        return False

    kp = []
    l = len(contourspt)
    ct = 0
    for i in range(l):
        p = i - step
        pp = i - s1
        if p < 0:
            p += l
            pp += l
        elif pp < 0:
            pp += l
        n = (i + step) % l
        nn = (i + s1) % l

        posPrev = contourspt[p][0]
        posPrevP = contourspt[pp][0]
        posCurr = contourspt[i][0]
        posNext = contourspt[n][0]
        posNextN = contourspt[nn][0]
        #first order derivative at point i w.r.t. x and y
        f1stderX = (posNext[0] - posPrev[0])/s1
        f1stderY = (posNext[1] - posPrev[1])/s1
        # second order derivative at point i w.r.t. x and y
        f2ndderX = (posNextN[0] - 2*posCurr[0] + posPrevP[0])/s2
        f2ndderY = (posNextN[1] - 2*posCurr[1] + posPrevP[1])/s2

        if f1stderX != 0 or f1stderY != 0:
            a = f2ndderX*f1stderY - f2ndderY*f1stderX
            b = np.power(np.power(f1stderX,2) + np.power(f1stderY,2), 3/2)
            curvature2D = float("{0:.5f}".format(a/b))

            #Check if contour contains any regular section of more than 
            # 20 percent of the contour length
            if np.abs(curvature2D) < 0.005:
                ct += 1
                if ct > l*0.2:
                    return True
            else:
                ct = 0
            if np.abs(curvature2D) < 0.0001 or np.abs(curvature2D) > 5: 
                curvature2D = 0 #local noise suppression
            #store the curvature values in a list
            kp.append(np.abs(curvature2D))

    # check the variance of curvatures values along the contour
    var = np.var(kp, ddof=1)
    if var < 0.01:
        print('Variance: ',var)
        return True
    return False


def main():
    gray = cv2.imread('D:/cnt.png', 0)
    #threshold the image using 250 as threhold value
    ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(gray,250,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    img1,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th1, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    #iterate through each contour
    for cnt in contours:
        if(len(cnt)>50): #neglect the small contours as noise
            flag = contourCurvature(cnt)
            if(flag):
                cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,0,255),3)

    cv2.imshow('Final image', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the output image showing only non-noisy(true) contours.
[image]

Though the final output image misses a few true contours, any other ideas to improve this algorithm are welcome here.

Comment: mm this is strange as there are visually less noisy contours taht you did not detect. I'd say extraction step is wrong. You should identify independent flat-color areas and grab the contour from neighboring white pixels around such flat colors. That said, its likely that OP actually has the contours, as most of the times this white lines come from visualization, as the segmentation procedure does not add contours between blobs

Comment: The challenge i got here is that a few contours contain smooth points in most its length but in a some region they consists of very irregular section, so such irregular part adds up the variance values makes the a noisy contour in total.
So may be if we add a check for the contours which have a section of regular curvature values with length more than certain threshold value then detect them as true contour.

Comment: What I'd do is not flag the maximum value, but integrate and normalize. Compute all angles in the contour, add them together and divide amount of points. Then there is an heuristic threshold there to set, but that should work

Comment: Yes, that seems  a feasible approach, i will try that. Just now i updated my answer as mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Is it possible to ask you to comment your solution a bit more? It seems to be in the right direction (testing it now) but some parts are not fully clear to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have added a some comments in code, please let me know if you have any specific query.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

1. Split the image matrix into a perfectly iterable proportion.
2. For each iterated space, fit the white pixels to a linear regression in the space.
3. Store the RSME (Root Mean Squared Error) from each section's linear model.
4. Calculate the standard deviation for all iterated sections.
5. Select a standard deviation that describes the threshold of tolerable "noise".

You'll need to experiment with different "iteration sizes" to find the best descriptor of noise.

If you want to compare relative noise levels *between* pictures, this problem is solved best using a convolution machine learning design.

Comment: I don't want to describe the image mathematically, I want to describe the noisi sections mathematically. i.e think of one such region as a polygon. How do i know the polygon is noisy?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if you would like help understanding how to implement any of the steps.

Comment: I have a personal vendetta against NN's

Comment: You dont need to use a nueral net for this, a simple linear kernel is what you want.

Comment: Just regression.

Answer (score 1):

You could first approximate each contour(or a part of it) with a polygonal curve using Douglas-Peucker, so that the maximal error is globally bounded, then perhaps consider

1. Comparing the perimeter of the approximation with the perimeter of the original curve
2. Compute the distance of each point on the original curve to the approximate polygonal curve, then compute the standard deviation of this data set.

Or you could take a crude and a fine polygonal approximation of the same contour and count the number of segments in the fine approximation per length of the crude approximation.